# Envoy proxy match route using regex

Tags: envoyproxy

I have a working Envoy proxy configuration that matches two routes `/name/foo/bar?mode=receive-data` and `/name/receive-data`. The Envoy configuration file looks something like this:

```
static_resources:
  ...
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          ...
          route_config:
            virtual_hosts:
            - ...
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/name/foo/bar?mode=receive-data"
                ...
              - match:
                  prefix: "/name/receive-data"
                ...
```

I need to update the configuration from using route `prefix` matching to `regex` match as explained in the [route.RouteMatch](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/route/route_components.proto#route-routematch) documentation. These two route deinitions must be converted to `/:name/foo/bar?mode=receive-data` and `/:name/receive-data` somehow, where `:name` can be `[a-z0-9]`. I've tried to write my own `regex:` for this, but with no success, so I'd appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations).

Comment: How is this related to envoy proxy? I search for `match.regex: XXX` definition.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation on 1.13.1:

```
- match:
   safe_regex:
    google_re2: {}
    regex: "\/.*\/foo\/bar"
  route:
    cluster: whatever
- match:
    safe_regex:
      google_re2: {}
      regex: "\/.*\/receive-data"
  route:
    cluster: somethingelse
```

Comment: Could the first regex potentially match `/something/foo/barS` or `/something/foo/bar/more` ?

Comment: See https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/test/tools/router_check/test/config/TestRoutes.yaml#L136 for more regex match examples including matching on :path